# Rails post from RSpec throws "no route matches"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, routes

I have route definition

```
post '/session/create' => 'sessions#create', as: 'create_session'
```

controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create

  def create
   # do some staff
  end
end
```

If I send post request using RestConsole - it works like it should, but if I try to send post from RSpec test like below - it throws exception.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsController do
  let(:user_data_to_post) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for :user }

  let(:user) do
    mock_model User
  end

  describe 'create new session should be successful' do 
    before do 
      post(create_session_path, user_data_to_post.to_json,
          {'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'})
    end

    it "should call search_by_email of User model" do
      User.should_recive(:search_by_email).with(user_data_to_post[:email])
    end
  end
end
```

error message:

```
Failure/Error: post(create_session_path, user_data_to_post.to_json,
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE=>"application/json", :controller=>"sessions",     :action=>"/session/create"}
 # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
post :create, user_data_to_post, format: :json
```

Firstly, `post` method expects the name of the action on the controller you passed to initial `describe`. Since you passed the path instead, it was treating the whole path as an action name, which obviously was not routed.

Secondly, `post` method signature is sth in line `post(action_name, raw_post_data(assigned only if string), params=nil, session=nil, flash=nil)` (in fact it is `post(action_name, *args)` but this is how those args are being processed. Sine you wanted to modify headers, you need to do this directly on a request:

```
@request['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/json'
```

or to pass `format: :json` along with params

Comment: Thx, now it works! Can you pls explain, what was wrong with my previous approach?